# Return Invalid Date, when trying to convert Json time String to locale time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I am trying to convert JSON time string to local time as below

```js
angular.forEach($scope.calendarData, function(item) {
  item.scheduleArray.startTime = new Date(item.scheduleArray.startTime);
  item.scheduleArray.endTime = new Date(item.scheduleArray.endTime);
});
```

#### For example

```
startTime = "1970-01-01T08:52:00.000Z"
```

But when I execute the code, it says **Invalid date**. How can I solve this problem

Comment: can you console your item.scheduleArray

Comment: because new Date("1970-01-01T08:52:00.000Z") is a valid date.

Comment: if `scheduleArray` is actually and array then `item.scheduleArray.startTime` will be undefined.

Comment: scheduleArray = {alert: "emailNotification"
endTime: "1970-01-01T08:52:00.000Z"
expanded: true
startTime: "1970-01-01T11:12:00.000Z"
title: "New Schedule"}' {...

Comment: Why if scheduleArray is an array then startTime becomes undefine plz tell me

Answer (score 0):

```js
let scheduleArray = {alert: "emailNotification", endTime: "1970-01-01T08:52:00.000Z", expanded: true, startTime: "1970-01-01T11:12:00.000Z", title: "New Schedule"};

let calendarData = [];
calendarData.push({'scheduleArray':scheduleArray});

angular.forEach(calendarData, function(item) {
  item.scheduleArray.startTime = new Date(item.scheduleArray.startTime);
  item.scheduleArray.endTime = new Date(item.scheduleArray.endTime);
  console.log(item.scheduleArray.startTime);
});

console.log(calendarData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
```